# Are players required to make conquests on their turn?

Tags: small-world

I did not find it clear in the rules if a player is required to make conquests on his/her turn.  Is it legal to turtle on your turn by not making any actions, redeploying troops and then scoring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not required. There's nothing wrong with just leaving everything exactly as is.

> Leaving in place one Race token in each Region they occupy,
>   the player **may** take all his other Active Race tokens from the
>   map back in hand and use them to conquer new Regions.

Note the "may".

Also:

> The active player can repeat this process to conquer as
>   many new Regions as he wishes during his turn, provided he
>   has enough Race tokens left to accomplish these successive
>   conquests.

"As many new Regions as he wishes." 0 might be as many as you wish.